# QuickDialog doesn't show 'prev' and 'next' toolbar as it's inputaccessoryview

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, quickdialog, inputaccessoryview

I created a test application and I can't get the next/previous toolbar to show above the keyboard while using the QuickDialog library. I tried toggling the `hiddenToolbar` property too. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

I think this commit is the issue. Switching back to a previous commit fixes the issue. https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog/commit/72446c1dd6669fa7843bd26267c085d3c2a84def#commitcomment-6008943